# PowerGUI Script Editor Settings

Tags: powershell, powergui

I am writing a powershell script using

> PowerGUI Script Editor

I am calling an xml file from the powershell the powershell GUI script editor will however powerGUI script editor keep on referencing the xml file from the my documents folder of the logged on user and not from the location specified in the folder structure.

Is there a **setting** in PowerGUI Script Editor where this can be changed.

Comment: Can you put a code example of what you're trying to do? This is a bit vague.

Comment: You need to use an absolute file path (rather than a relative one) or explicitly change the directory with `set-location` to the folder you want to use.